# Pandas ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. when calculating max value among previous and current element

Tags: python, pandas

I am computing the supertrend of candles using pandas. I have one column called `up`, and another column called `dn` in my dataframe as defined in the code below.

I need to compute the `trendUp` feature based on the following criteria:

- If `close` of the previous row is greater than the `trendUp` of current row, then `trendUp` should be equal to maximum value among the `up` of current row and `trendUp` for previous row.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
candles_df['up'] = candles_df['hl2'] - (factor * candles_df['atr'])
candles_df['dn'] = candles_df['hl2'] + (factor * candles_df['atr'])

candles_df['trendUp'] = candles_df['up']
candles_df['trendUp'] = np.where(candles_df['close'].shift(1) > candles_df['trendUp'], max([candles_df['up'], candles_df['trendUp'].shift(1)]) , candles_df['up'])
```

However, when I execute this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_trend.py", line 178, in <module>
    trend('instrument')
  File "test_trend.py", line 153, in trend
    candles_df['trendUp'] = np.where(candles_df['close'].shift(1) > candles_df['trendUp'], max([candles_df['up'], candles_df['trendUp'].shift(1)]) , candles_df['up'])   
  File "/home/aniruddh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1469, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

At first I thought the error was corresponding to the np.where condition clause. However, the code works if I replace the `max()` function with a static quantity.

How should I go about this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) instead of `max` to calculate element-wise maximum of array elements. `np.maximum` compare two arrays and returns a new array containing the element-wise maxima.

```
import numpy as np

candles_df['trendUp'] = np.where(
    candles_df['close'].shift(1) > candles_df['trendUp'], 
    np.maximum(candles_df['up'], candles_df['trendUp'].shift(1)), 
    candles_df['up'])
```